# Get directory path from content URI

Tags: java, android, uri

I'm using the SDK's [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) intent to let the user select a directory. Here's the code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_FOLDER = 1;

// …

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_folder: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FOLDER);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_FOLDER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        addFolder(data.getData());
    }
}

private void addFolder(Uri uri) {
    Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri));
    Log.d(TAG, "Folder added: " + docUri.toString());
}
```

I have an URI (probably) pointing to the folder I just selected. Here's an example output: `Folder added: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/FF30-E80D%3AImages/document/FF30-E80D%3AImages`.

Now, I need to get the absolute path, something translating in this case to `/storage/sdcard1/Images`. I found some code in [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java#L257) which seems to work, but not for SD cards, which is my main use case.

I could probably split the URI on `%3A`, if the preceding part is "primary", then use the first external storage path, if it's something else, use the second one, but it feels wrong… There's probably a more deterministic way to achieve this?

Edit: here's some background on this. I don't need the path to manage the files. But how to present this to the user? I definitely can't show him `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/FF30-E80D%3AImages/document/FF30-E80D%3AImages`, that's just scary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I need to get the absolute path, something translating in this case to /storage/sdcard1/Images.

That is not possible. There is no requirement that the `Uri` point to a file at all, let alone a file that you can access.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content and read it in that way. This is not significantly different than how you would handle a URL to a Web server (use `HttpUrlConnection` to get an `InputStream` on the Web page or other content).

> But how to present this to the user?

I don't know what "this" is. However, [you can get the suggested display name associated with the content](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#metadata).

Comment: `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` is a start, but as I mentioned, "this" is a folder. Let's say the user selects an "images" folder. Is it the one on the SD-card? Is it the one on the internal memory? Just getting the name (which is what `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` contains for folders) is not enough.

Comment: @Kernald: Then let the user associate their own tag with their selection, just before or just after making the selection, rather than assuming that the users would understand a filesystem path, even if you could get one.