# How to access files in a directory given a content URI?

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32993476/8660130).
I got content Uri of a directory using  ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.
and got something like this

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ASHAREit%2Fpictures
```

as result upon selecting a directory.
Now, my problem is how can i access all the files inside the directory (and preferably subdirectories too).

Answer (score 12):

Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to create [a `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) for your tree. Then, [use `listFiles()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#listFiles()) to get a list of the documents and sub-trees inside of that tree. For those where `isDirectory()` returns `true`, you can further traverse the tree. For the rest, use `getUri()` to get a `Uri` to the document, which you can use with `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get the content, if needed.

Comment: You got a lot of answers, but you never show code. Could you please show detailed code. I dont have Android Studio, but i use java straight. And i dont know how to piece this from scrap.

Comment: Please note that this won't work if you don't convert the folder's Uri to an Uri that represents the files under it; This is possible via the following method: ```val childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uri,DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri))
```

Comment: @CommonsWare I Understand your approach Thanks, But I cant get file path from those uri list from tree. Exception arise.

Comment: @NoorHossain: "But I cant get file path from those uri list from tree" -- correct, because documents do not have to be on the filesystem. Nothing involving the Storage Access Framework or `DocumentsContract` involves the filesystem. Given a document `Uri`, use the document `Uri` itself, such as with `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` or with `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` and the various methods on `DocumentFile`.

Comment: @commonsware thanks, I found the approach,  it seems that its a different world from filepath eg. io.file,  is that, android goes more complex?

Comment: @NoorHossain: The Storage Access Framework is an abstraction layer. Documents can come from the filesystem, from cloud storage providers, from encrypted on-device stores, from a local network file server, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I am very new to Android Development, and was stuck on understanding CommonsWare's answer (among other resources) for a long time. This [resource](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/blob/main/ActionOpenDocumentTree/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/ktfiles/DirectoryFragmentViewModel.kt) was also helpful.

1. You need the [DocumentFile AndroidX library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/documentfile), so add that to your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1"
```

2. Once you've gotten your content URI which contains the `tree`, you can use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri`

```kotlin
        val filenamesToDocumentFile = mutableMapOf<String, DocumentFile>()
        val documentsTree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri) ?: return
        val childDocuments = documentsTree.listFiles()
        for (childDocument in childDocuments) {
            childDocuments[0].name?.let {
            filenamesToDocumentFile[it] = childDocument
            }
        }
```

Now I'm off to figure out how to use this DocumentFile... (hint: `val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(childDocument.uri)`)

Answer (score 3):

Here a snippet related to @CommonsWare [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942134/1373333).

Launch the file picker with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

```
startActivityForResult(
    Intent.createChooser(Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), "Choose directory"),
    IMPORT_FILE_REQUEST
)
```

Receive the `Uri` of the selected directory from file picker

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        IMPORT_FILE_REQUEST -> {
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return
            val uri = data?.data ?: return
            // get children uri from the tree uri
            val childrenUri =
                DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                    uri,
                    DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri)
                )
            // get document file from children uri
            val tree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, childrenUri)
            // get the list of the documents
            tree?.listFiles()?.forEach { doc ->
                // get the input stream of a single document
                val iss = contentResolver.openInputStream(doc.uri)
                // prepare the output stream
                val oss = FileOutputStream(File(filesDir, doc.name))
                // copy the file
                CopyFile { result ->
                    println("file copied? $result")
                }.execute(iss, oss)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Copy file with `AsyncTask` (feel free to use threads, coroutines..)

```
class CopyFile(val callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) :
    AsyncTask<Closeable, Int, Boolean>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg closeables: Closeable): Boolean {
        if (closeables.size != 2) throw IllegalArgumentException("two arguments required: input stream and output stream")
        try {
            (closeables[0] as InputStream).use { iss ->
                (closeables[1] as OutputStream).use { oss ->
                    iss.copyTo(oss)
                    return true
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean) {
        callback.invoke(result)
    }
}
```